# Bash regex with sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

Trying to get only words that come before "/", I wrote:

```
T='He/She is a very handsome/beautiful man/woman indeed.'
echo "$T" | sed -E 's#\b(.*)/(.*)\b#\1#g'
```

However, I only got to make it work in the last occurrence (although I'm using "g" in sed sentence):

```
He/She is a very handsome/beautiful man.
```

My desired output is: "He is a very handsome man indeed."

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove non-space characters after every slash you can use:

```
$ sed 's:/\S*::g' <<<'He/She is a very handsome/beautiful man/woman indeed.'
He is a very handsome man indeed.
```

The pattern, `:/\S*:`, matches a slash followed by zero or more non-space characters. The replacement string, `::`,  is empty and it is applied globally `g`. The [`<<<`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings) is a here-string that passes input to sed.

Comment: Can you help me understand this regex?

Comment: The basic `\S` is the way to go. You can also use the extended regex `\w` (word chars)to the same effect, though not all seds support extended regex. E.g. `sed -E 's:/\w*::g'` The word chars are equivalent to `[:alnum:]` + `'_'` (e.g. `sed 's:/[[:alnum:]_]*::g'`).

Answer (score 3):

A POSIX compliant one:

```
T='He/She is a very handsome/beautiful man/woman indeed.'
echo "$T" | sed 's:/[^ ]*::g'
```